# jquery restore draggables position after reloading site

Tags: jquery, css, html, position, draggable

I am trying to drag a div from one container to anonther and place them there.
That works.
The problem is when i try to save and reload the positions.
The draggable & droppable div should be dragged from the #dragdelete div to the #tagDropPoint div

```
$('.resizeDiv')
    .draggable({ revert: "invalid", snap: "#dragDelete", snapMode: "inner", containment: "#draggableArea" });

$('#tagDropPoint').droppable({accept: '.resizeDiv',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        setActive(lastXmlTag);
        ui.draggable.resizable();
        }
 });
```

This is how i get the positions

```
$('.resizeDiv').mouseup(
    function(){
        var position = $(this).position();
        var dropAreaPos = $('#tagDropPoint').position();

        var xpos = position.left - dropAreaPos.left;
        var ypos = position.top - dropAreaPos.top;

        var width = $(this).width();
        var height = $(this).height();

        var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
        lastXmlTag = thisId;
        updateDDXMLAttr(xpos, ypos, width, height, thisId);

    }
);
```

HTML for the drag:
     
            
                Drag Tags here.

```
        <div class="ddSpacer">&nbsp;</div>

        <div id="dragDelete" class="dragDelete" style="height: {$this->heightListBox}px;">
            <p class="dynConTagHeading">XML-Tags</p>
            <div id="dynConTagsContainer">

            </div>
        </div>
            <p style="clear: both">&nbsp;</div>
        </div>
```

The position and size values are stored in a hidden field and reloaded after refreshing the site.
The draggableArea div is shown in a jquery dialog.
But the position are not the same when reloading. How can it be fixed.

Comment: Please create a JSFIDDLE : http://jsfiddle.net/ for the same.

Comment: Now i created a jsfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/DSU72/3/) But there is no reloading. I hope i can explain the problem without full functions in jsfiddle. As u can see there is a draggable div that u can dragg to the grey area. On reloading page the i get the values  xpos = position.left - dropAreaPos.left;ypos = position.top - dropAreaPos.top; from POST (in jsf there is now none such of hidden fields i use) My Problem is: when i put the x pos and ypos through $('.resizeDiv').css() back to the div the position is not the same as before

Comment: I am checking your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The positions may have moved due to paddings, margins, absolute postions and may be due to some coding error.

If you could create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for the same then it would be easier to debug and help you.

Answer (score 2):

Use a cookie to store the position or a serversided pagerendering technique like php or ASP.NET to deliver the Page with the Div at the correct position.

That the page div is at the original position is the correct HTML behaviour, there is nothing to "fix" this behaviour, this is how it is intended to work. If you want it to behave differently use a cookie or render the page differently.

Comment: Storing the positions is not that problem. There also no problem to get these values. The only problem i have is that the positions i get from $('#tagDropPoint').position() are not the same on "reseting" the div by css.

Comment: @Livingstone There may be a number of reasons like paddings, margins, absolute positions which may cause you getting incorect.

Comment: Oh ok, i used absolute position for the surrounding div and relative position for the draggable div. Ill check that

Answer (score 0):

Javascript(including Jquery) is only browser manipulation. To save, you need to either save settings to a DB or file.

Comment: Maybe i did not explain the problem i have exactly. I get the values (xpos, ypos ... ) from POST. And loading these values to each div css works also. The problem i have is that the position are not exactly the same. They are moved lightly

Comment: the positions of the divs are not excatly the same as before reloading.